# Vue 3 defineExpose doesn't expose child method or property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I have a Parent and child components as the following :

Parent Component :

```
<script setup>
import ChildComp from '@/components/ChildComp.vue'
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const childComp = ref(null)
const clickMe = () => {
    console.log(childComp.value.selectedRadio) // <====== UNDEFINED
    childComp.value.hello() // <======= RETURNS hello is not a function
};
</script>

<template>
  <ChildComp ref="childComp" />
  <button @click="clickMe()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</template>
```

Child component :

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const selectedRadio = ref("")
selectedRadio.value = "test"

const hello = () => {
   console.log("hey from child");
};

defineExpose({
 hello,
 selectedRadio,
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Hi! I am the child component</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

As described in code, when the button is clicked I have the following errors :

```
console.log(childComp.value.selectedRadio) // <====== UNDEFINED
 childComp.value.hello() // <======= RETURNS hello is not a function
```

Knowing that the childComp returns correctly the component Object and when accessing `childComp.value.$.exposed` I can see both `selectedRadio` property and `hello` function.

```
Vue version : 3.2.45
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: update `vite` package. it will also update the built-in SFC compiler where the issue with defineExpose is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding : `@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.45` in my devDependencies

Comment: If you're encountering this issue and you're not using the `@vue/compiler-sfc` dependency, try updating `vite`. The compiler is already built-in, and updating `vite` resolved the issue with exposing for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your code is fine, take a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-734xnz) pls.

Comment: Indeed on StackBlitz it works but not in my dev environment..
What could cause this issue? Thanks

Comment: @Obama hey mate, take a look at package.json at stackblitz example, maybe you will find the cause :)

Comment: Wow!! I just added  "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.45" in my devDependencies and it works!! Why in your opinion?